# Subclassing com.android.okhttp.AndroidShimResponseCache in application

Tags: android, httpresponsecache

I want to subclass `ResponseCache` and use a subclass of `com.android.okhttp.AndroidShimResponseCache` as an internal delegate.

In particular I want to add a small pre-caching method to the class, similar to `AndroidShimResponseCache.put`, but with my own files in the `Response` to be cached.

Then I would make  my class (that inherits from `ResponseCache`) the system default.

How can I access `AndroidShimResponseCache` in my code to subclass it in my application?

I'm not able to get it from any repo or library on my device.

Comment: What is magic about that `AndroidShimResponseCache`, compared to [the one in OkHttp itself](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-android-support/src/main/java/okhttp3/AndroidShimResponseCache.java)?

Comment: @CommonsWare I want to add a method to it to put some files into the http cache as a pre-caching measure. If I directly use the `HttpResponseCache.put` method the underlying `OkHttp` stack refuses to cache it and returns null. The UrlConnection passed to the `put` is checked for its type and rejected.

Comment: Why are you bothering trying to mess with the forked OkHttp that underlies `HttpUrlConnection`, rather than just using OkHttp directly, where all of this is exposed to you?

Comment: Large existing application that uses `HttpUrlConnection` everywhere. I'm trying to pre-fill the cache without making a network call (by having some resources packaged along with the app). One solution is to implement my own cache entirely and make it the default. I'm looking for a way to use the built-in cache.

Comment: Looks like I have to use reflection to get those classes.